# How can I remove this alert badge from my settings icon?

Tags: ios

- I'm on the iOS 12.1.2 version.
- I have no other alerts in my settings.

But this just won't go away:

[image]

I think it's related to prodding for iCloud upgrades, but I'm just not seeing anything at all. How can I get rid of this badge?

Comment: If you open Settings and scroll through, is any of the entries marked?

Comment: @nohillside Nope, none of them.

Comment: Which iOS version is installed? Please include the specific number, not just "the latest".

Comment: It’s iOS 12.1.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in recent version(s?) of iOS. The fix is to log out of iCloud and log back in. I have the badge as well, but haven't tried the fix yet.

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/9hikbo/ios_12_settings_badge_wont_go_away_no_pending/):

> So on a hunch, I signed out of iCloud and back in. Badge gone!
>
> When I signed back in, there was a prompt about not having backed up in over 7 days. So maybe there is a bug that's causing that to lurk under the hood somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things it could be:

- Go to the top of your settings and under your Apple ID check for any notifications
- Go to general -> software update and see if there is a software update that is needed to be downloaded
- Go to iCloud in settings and check for any notifications